# broken image on my django production site. Why is it?

Tags: python, django, heroku, path, media

I just product my site using Heroku and I got a odd problem with my media images broken.
Here is my site structure on Heroku.

```
 -- app
    -- manage.py
    -- mysite
       -- settings
         -- __init__.py
         -- base.py
         -- production.py
    -- static
       -- media
          -- product
            -- images
              -- 
       -- static_dirs
       -- static_root
```

In my app/mysite/settings/ **init**.py

```
from .base import *
try:
    from .local import *
    live = False
except:
    live = True
if live:
    from .production import *
```

and in my base.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'    
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')    
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_root')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'static_dirs'),
)    
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)
```

and in my production.py, I annotated as below.

```
# Static asset configuration
# import os
# BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
# STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
# STATICFILES_DIRS = (
# os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
# )
```

Finally, I ran server and I got still broken image shown on my page.
When I look the image carefully through "google inspect element",I can still see the probably right path as below.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="/media/products/images/aws.png">
```

But when I see my /static/media/products/images/ folder, there were images created on development statge only, not the images I just created on production site. (aws.png)

As still beginner for django development, It is a tough to find answer even after few hour's googling.

Please let me sleep & thanks always.

Comment: In the directory listing above (at the start of your question) you spelled "media" wrong. Is that the problem, or just a mistake in your post?

Comment: Oh it's just my mistake, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Django is serving static files in debug mode only. The situation and the solutions are explained in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

You need to run collectstatic on your production box.